# logstash load plugin configuration on server restart

Tags: logstash

so if I understand correctly to load logstash with some input config I need to run

```
bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
```

how I automate this process so if my server will restart it will auto load some configs?

the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html) not talking about this at all

edit: I am not 100% sure but it looks like the configs files shout be on `/etc/logstash/conf.d/`

Answer (score 2):

use this command for systems that use upstart

```
sudo systemctl start logstash.service
```

The required configuration file for upstart systems is

```
/etc/init/logstash.conf
```